# JAXB, unmarshalling from XML, missing fields as null

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

XML inputs are unmarshalled with **moxy** using namespaces with **@XmlPath**. It works fine. However, if a field from the xml is missing, then it is assigned an empty string after unmarshalling is done. I would like however null to be assigned in such cases. I put two simplified XML examples down below. I would like the element b to be assigned an empty string in the first example while a null value in the second example.
Do you have any ideas? Thank you also in advance.

```
e.g. 1.
<ft:root>
    <ft:a>hhh</ft:a>
    <ft:b></ft:b>
</ft:root>


e.g. 2.
<ft:root>
    <ft:a>hhh</ft:a>
</ft:root>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was solved after I did a mvn clean install. Sorry for bothering you.